# settimeout this. RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: javascript

Why RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded in this.startTime();

```
startTime() {
    $('.m-codeModal-resendTimer').html(this.sectmr);
    this.sectmr--;
    if (this.sectmr < 0) {
        this.sectmr = 0;
        $('.m-codeModal-resendErrorNow').fadeIn(0);
        $('.m-codeModal-resendErrorSec').fadeOut(0);
        $('.m-codeModal-sorry').fadeOut(0);
    }
    setTimeout(this.startTime(), 1000);
}
```

Comment: You probably want to _pass_ a function to the timer, not to instantly call it.

Answer (score 2):

Several things...

- Add a `function` keyword to define your `startTime` function.
- Remove the `this` keyword in the `setTimeout` reference to `startTime`.
- The function [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout) takes a callback as a parameter. You, instead of passing a callback parameter to the function, are actually calling the `startTime` function before the `setTimeout` function ever has a chance to evaluate and count down 1000 milliseconds.

Here's a simplified example:

```js
var count = 0;
function startTime() {
    count++;
    document.getElementById('count').innerHTML = count;
    setTimeout(startTime, 1000);
}
startTime();
```

```html
<div id="count"></div>
```

Comment: It won't work since `startTime` uses `this` internally.

Answer (score 1):

You're in an infinite loop.

by calling startTime() function call for the first time, you are recursively calling startTime again once you enter the setTimeout function.

In your startTime() function as it is now, there is no way to exit it once you enter.

Maybe you'd want to try

```
if (this.sectmr < 0) {
  ...
  return;
}
```

by adding the return statement, once your sectmr goes below zero and enters the if loop, you should be kicked out of the function. I'm not sure what your end goal is, however. Please be a bit more descriptive in the opening question.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're doing `setTimeout(this.startTime(), 1000);`, executing `this.startTime()` and using its return value (undefined in this case) as the timer handler. Just remove the `()`.